# Выпадает паддинг из контейнера

Tags: html, css, padding

Есть `.container`:

```
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

И он не совсем правильно центрует:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На медиасайзе `320px` все нормально, по `8px`. Но если начинать растягивать, то `padding` справа начинает постепенно уменьшаться и затем вовсе пропадает. В чем может быть проблема? Верстаю на флексах, подключен flexboxgrid2

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  min-width: 302px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 992px;
  }
}


/* Header */

.header {
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.16);
}

.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.location {
  display: none;
}

.header__buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__button {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 13px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.header__button--sign-up {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  padding: 14px 15px 13px 15px;
  /* margin-right: 12px; */
}

.header__button--register {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 15.5px 13px 15.5px;
  border: none;
}

.header__button--basket {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header__button--basket {
    display: flex;
    width: 19px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url("../images/logo-basket.svg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__nav">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="./images/logo.svg" width="92" height="11" alt="UberEats logo">
      </div>
      <div class="location">
        <form action="#" class="location__form">
          <select name="time" id="" class="location__time">
            <option value="ASAP">ASAP</option>
          </select>
          <p class="location__title">to</p>
          <input class="location__address" type="text" placeholder="ul. Bolshaya Dmitrovka, 22">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="header__buttons">
        <button class="header__button header__button--sign-up">Sign up</button>
        <button class="header__button header__button--register">Register</button>
        <button class="header__button header__button--basket"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Было бы намного проще ответить на вопрос, если бы вы приложили код, в котором такая проблема возникает.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку сам. После хедера идет тег мэйн, в котором есть карточки товаров. Картинка товара имела бОльшую ширину, чем родитель. Соответственно вопрос решен заданием подходящей ширины. Всем спасибо.